# View PDF on Mobile with downloading

Tags: html, pdf, mobile

I have the following link to a PDF document on my website:

```
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/mydocument.pdf">Example</a>
```

On PC it opens up the document using a PDF reader, however on mobile and tablet devices it asks the user to "Download" the PDF to their local storage. Is there a way to make it open PDF documents on mobile and tablet without downloading? I want the view to remain in the browser.

Comment: have you tried opening the page in Google Chrome?

Comment: @Satya Yes I've used Google Chrome on the mobile devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Google Docs Viewer by appending URL

https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=

https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://mywebsite.com/mydocument.pdf